# SpelEvaluationException: Attempted to call method on null context object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-11, spring-el

I'm trying to do a simple cache task. I have a `Holiday` object, which has two fields: `referenceDate` and `isHoliday`. I then have a method that will make a HTTP request to a rest api in order to check if a date is a holiday or not. What I want to achieve is: if the current cached `Holiday` object has the same referenceDate as the one passed as a parameter, return the cached value. I have a specific class to perform that check. Here is the code:

**Holiday class**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Holiday {
    public LocalDate referenceDate;
    public boolean isHoliday;
}
```

**CacheService class**

```
@DomainService
public class CacheService {

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    public boolean isReferenceDateCached(final LocalDate referenceDate){
        final Holiday holiday = (Holiday) cacheManager.getCache("holiday").get("holidaycheck");
        return(holiday.getReferenceDate().equals(referenceDate));
    }
}
```

**HolidatInfraService class**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
@Slf4j
public class HolidayInfraService {

    @Autowired
    private final CacheService cacheService;

    @Cacheable(value = "holiday", key = "holidaycheck", condition = "#cacheService.isReferenceDateCached(#holidayDateToCheck)")
    public Holiday isHoliday(final LocalDate holidayDateToCheck) {
        //some code to call a rest api
    }

}
```

And this is the error I get from my unit test when I try to `holidayInfraService.isHoliday(someDate)`:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method isReferenceDateCached(java.time.LocalDate) on null context object
```

From this exception message seems pretty obvious that `cacheService` is null. However, when I debbuged the code and got inside `isHoliday`, `cacheService` is not null. Maybe it hasn't been autowired yet by the time the annotation runs? It is also the first time I'm working with SPEL, so maybe something there too. If in fact `cacheService` is not autowired yet, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using the `@Cacheable(...)` annotation, Spring will evaluate that SpEL expression with the context class `MethodBasedEvaluationContext`.  This will set the root object to be a `CacheExpressionRootObject`, and property lookups will be performed using that root object.

Since you are trying to refer to a property on a bean, the easiest solution would be to directly reference that bean in the SpEL expression.  This is done with an `@` (e.g. `@myBeanName`).  Spring will then look for a bean with that name in the `ApplicationContext`.  Remember that a bean defined without an explicit name will be named using the lower camel-came of the class name.  For example, a class with the name `MyBeanName` will have a bean name of `myBeanName`.

Try changing your `condition=` block to

```java
@Cacheable(value = "holiday", key = "holidaycheck", condition = "@cacheService.isReferenceDateCached(#holidayDateToCheck)")
public Holiday isHoliday(final LocalDate holidayDateToCheck) {
    //some code to call a rest api
}
```

Comment: Ben, that caused a different error: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'cacheService' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheExpressionRootObject' - maybe not public or not valid?. After getting this error I tried setting the variable to public modifier, but nothing changed

Comment: @William Ok, I was worried that may happen as well.  This happens when you try a similar thing with `@PreAuthorize`.  Have you tried referring to the CacheService bean directly?  Try `condition = "@CacheService.isReferenceDateCached(#holidayDateToCheck)`.  This will lookup the bean in the ApplicationContext and use that.

Comment: @William I edited my answer to use the bean reference strategy

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it. I will look further into the operators #, {, @ and so forth... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SpEL's `MethodBasedEvaluationContext` to access method variable, you need to use `#`, but no `#` is needed for class variables. Property lookup will automatically find getter for the property without `#` symbol. So, your SpEL should be

```
cacheService.isReferenceDateCached(#holidayDateToCheck)
```

And if this SpEL won't work, try creating getter method for `cacheService`.

Comment: Hi, Geobreze. Your answer also caused a different error about modifiers. Here's the exception I got when tried your solution: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'cacheService' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheExpressionRootObject' - maybe not public or not valid?

Comment: Did you try adding `getCacheService` public method?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Cacheable(value = "holiday", key = "holidaycheck", condition = "#{cacheService.isReferenceDateCached(#holidayDateToCheck)}")
public Holiday isHoliday(final LocalDate holidayDateToCheck) {
    //some code to call a rest api
}
```